# redirect_uri not working with trailing backslash

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I use nuxt auth to do a social login:

```
    access_token_endpoint: 'https://****.**/social',
    access_type: 'offline',
    client_id: '688267128737845',
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    redirect_uri: 'http:localhost:3000/account/aanmelden',
    response_type: 'code',
    token_key: 'jwt',
    userinfo_endpoint: false
```

With the `/account/aanmelden` the code works, but when I add a backslash `/account/aanmelden/` I cannot log in anymore.

I've added `http://localhost:3000/account/aanmelden` and `http://localhost:3000/account/aanmelden/` to my Valid OAuth Redirect URIs options on the Facebook app.

Does anyone know this happens?

Comment: Did you change the value of `redirect_uri` in the shown config data as well?

Comment: The API call to exchange the code returned from the login dialog, for an access token, requires the *exact* same `redirect_uri` value that was used in the login dialog call, to be passed again (that is a security measure) - so unless your system is able to handle this dynamically, and match that parameter value to the value actually used in the login dialog call, this won’t work.

Comment: Thanks! Consulted our back-end dev and the api call to facebook was incorrect!

Comment: @misorude if you want to put your remark in an answer I'll gladly accept it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API call to exchange the code returned from the login dialog, for an access token, requires the exact same `redirect_uri` value that was used in the login dialog call, to be passed again – that is a security measure.

Unless your system is able to handle this dynamically, and match that parameter value to the value actually used in the login dialog call, you probably won’t be able to use the two versions, with and without trailing slash, interchangeably.

Comment: We ended up with a dynamic `redirect_uri` in the back-end based on the `return_uri` in the front end so they're always in sync.